# SQL Query Optimizing on large data

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm trying to figure out why my below code goes from 2sec run time to 23min run time simply by adding the indicated where clause (at the bottom).

A fix would be awesome but also trying to understand why thats causing it to run 4573468975468% longer, (not working with a terribly large data set, < 100,000).

```
USE [HDWarehouse]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

with AncestryTree as (
  select WbsCode, ParentWbsCode
  from ProgressItemsView
  where ParentWbsCode is not null
  and
  BidMasterJobCode = '01525'
  union all
  select ProgressItemsView.WbsCode, t.ParentWbsCode
  from AncestryTree t 
  join ProgressItemsView on t.WbsCode = ProgressItemsView.ParentWbsCode
  where BidMasterJobCode ='01525'
)
Select ResourceCode, ResourceType, AccountCode, CostItemWbsCode, [Progress Level], TotalCost, ISNULL([Percent Complete]*totalcost/100,0) as [Earned Value], IsSuspended
from(
    Select *
    from(
        select * 
        from ResourceEmploymentsView y
        left join 
            (
            select t.WbsCode as [Resource Level], t.ParentWbsCode as [Progress Level], v.QuantityCompletePercent as [Percent Complete], BidMasterJobCode as jobcode
            from AncestryTree T
                left join ProgressItemsView V
                on t.ParentWbsCode = v.WbsCode
                and BidMasterJobCode = '01525'
            where v.HasProgressRecorded = '1'
            --Bring in all WBS codes 
            union
            select wbscode, wbscode, QuantityCompletePercent, BidMasterJobCode as jobcode
            from ProgressItemsView
                where IsLeaf = '1'
                and
                HasProgressRecorded = '1'
                and
                BidMasterJobCode = '01525'
            ) x
        --on y.BidMasterJobCode = x.BidMasterJobCode
        --and
        on y.CostItemWbsCode = x.[Resource Level]
        )z
    left join
        (select bidmasterjobcode as jobecode, wbscode, issuspended 
        from CostItemsView
        --where IsSuspended <> '1'
        ) CI
    on z.BidMasterJobCode = ci.jobecode
    and
    z.CostItemWbsCode = ci.WbsCode
    )q
where q.BidMasterJobCode = '01525'
and q.ResourceType <> 'Resource Assembly'
and IsSuspended <> '1' --this is what slow down my code, without it it runs in seconds...
```

Comment: Please post execution plan and indexes on relevant tables. On top of that, I'd strongly suggest asking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you considered switching from the left join to an inner join for the join to `select bidmasterjobcode as jobecode, wbscode, issuspended 
        from CostItemsView
        where IsSuspended <> '1'` and putting the IsSuspended in that where clause?

Comment: google "SQL COVERING INDEX".   Learn what it is, and add one for this query and you should get your performance back.

Comment: @Grax tried that with the same preformance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will venture a guess that IsSuspended is a low-cardinality column, most likely a flag with two values. If so, the server may see your predicate of:

```
IsSuspended <> '1'
```

and it is probably making a worst-case assessment, and you will probably see an Index Scan or Table Scan in your query plan. If you add this flag to the end of an existing index, involving BidMasterJobCode and ResourceType, you will probably get your performance back. When making these kinds of composite indexes, and even when making covering indexes, make sure you think carefully about which columns appear there, and in what order. Typically, the high-cardinality columns should appear first, with lesser cardinality columns appearing in descending order. This helps the optimizer make a good choice of index.

In your case, the {IsSuspended <> '1'} is probably making an assumption that it will need to read the vast majority of rows, particularly if the percentage of rows with {IsSuspended  = '1'} is relatively low.

Comment: Thanks for the help and detailed explaination, I really appreciate it. I am currently reading up on covering indexes and will be adding one to the DB.

Comment: Glad to help. If you still run into performance issues with this query, please post the execution plan and schema information, and we can help supply optimization ideas.

Comment: Everything is running smoothly now thanks so much.  Went thru my query execution plan (on my larger query, similair logic to the one i posted) and every time i saw table scan or RID lookup I added a covering index ordered by cardinality to the respected table.  Report used to run in +30min now down to 20s.  Still a little confuced about the difference between 'Index Key Columns' or 'Included Columns'... have some reading to do.

Comment: Key columns are things that are searched. For example, you could include columns from your WHERE clause as key columns. Included columns are columns that you would like returned, such as non-searched columns included in your SELECT clause. This reduces I/O for certain queries, by "covering" them. The presence of these included columns means that the data engine does not need to go into the table, but can retrieve all of the data from the index. Keeping these included columns out of the key reduces the key size (limited to 900 bytes), and they are not considered in the key column limit (16).

Comment: So, if you don't need to search/filter by certain columns, but want those columns in your index, in order to cover queries, add them as included columns instead of keys.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks again, really apprciate the help.